# If a thread listens to an event and thread has been aborted what happens to the event?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Say if a thread has subscribed to an event and the thread has been aborted. But the object is still there. So what happens to the raised event now?

For example: Say I am listening to Process.Exited event, and the thread which subscribed to that event has been aborted. How the CLR inform to my application about the event?

---

Thanks for quick replies. I understand the event will be raised on thread on which the publisher raises the event. I can clearly understand/verify it when its coming from my project. But what if I subscribe to others? For ex: Process.Exited which I have no control.

---

Answer:

When SynchronizingObject is Nothing, methods that handle the Exited event are called on a thread from the system thread pool. For more information about system thread pools, see ThreadPool.

As Hans pointed our it will be invoked on a thread pool thread.

Thanks a lot. Stackoverflow rocks!!,
Regards,
Dreamer.

Comment: Do you mean an event from the C# keyword (ie. wrapped delegate), or a Windows Event object ([`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) or [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx))?

Comment: HI Richard, I mean C# keyword even (wrapped delegate)

Comment: Threads don't listen to events, you are mutating thread-independent program state.  Process.Exited will be raised on a threadpool thread, an implementation detail for that particular event.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Yes it will be called on thread pool thread.

Answer (score 3):

A *thread* doesn't subscribe to an event. An event handler is attached to an event. It's up to the event *publisher* to decide on what thread those events are raised.

Threads and events are almost always orthogonal - event publishers generally just call the event handlers on whatever thread "naturally" notices that the logical event has occurred (e.g. the UI thread for a UI event).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Say, I have subscribed to Process.Exited event by providing the event handler (delegate). How does it decides in which thread it should call the event? What happens if whatever thread it chooses to call has been waiting/suspended etc..?

Comment: @Dreamer: It's ultimately up to the publisher, but usually if a handler needs to do most of its work on a particular thread, the handler itself will marshal the call... which means it's up to that marshaller to decide what to do if the thread is busy/dead/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is called from the thread that raises the event. It doesn't matter which thread subscribed to an event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried? The subscribed object (that is referenced by the event delegate) just stays around on the heap (not garbage collected), until the event gets actively detached (e.g. by the event source being garbage collected)

**Edit** as others have pointed out, the event gets invoked on whatever thread that raises the event anyway.

Comment: I can see when the events are raised by me or from one of my projects/team projects. What happens on the events I dont have control? For ex: Process.Exited.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.80).aspx, by subscribing to event you are writing custom code that is executed when event is invoked (presumably in same thread where event is invoked). If you want your application to no longer listen for that event you should unsubscribe your event handler, as described in linked msdn page.